# Hide all hidden mongoose methods and properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I use nuxt 3. I have this code on my serverside.

```
  findAuthorByEmail(email: string, showPassword = false) {
    return Author.findOne({ email })
      .select(showPassword ? "" : "-password_hash")
      .lean();
  },
```

Inside my `/server/api/login.post.ts` i return it here:

```
  return {
    token,
    author,
  };
```

Nuxt has the feature to provide the types for my front end. What should my query look like so that my response only provides the properties which are available? If I try to use for example `$isDefault` then it does not work of course.

Here is also my mongoose model:

```
import { Document } from "mongoose";
import { AuthorI } from "~~/types";
import { conn } from "../configuration/connection";
import { authorConfig } from "../configuration/author";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password_hash: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: authorConfig.password_min_length,
  },
  name: {
    maxlength: authorConfig.name_length,
    trim: true,
    type: String,
  },
  family_name: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: authorConfig.family_name_length,
    trim: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: authorConfig.description_length,
    trim: true,
  },
  props: {},
  username: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    maxlength: authorConfig.username_length,
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
    immutable: true,
  },
  enabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
});

export const Author = conn.model<AuthorModel>("Author", schema);

interface AuthorModel extends AuthorI, Document {}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

use .lean() method. check official doc [mongoose lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html://)